# How to ask Linux g++ to correctly compile header files contained within another header file?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I have  a question about how to fix the following Linux Makefile code:

```
g++  -g -Wall -I"./" -I"../CameraControlLib" -I"./Cameras" -I"../../Utilities/DataServer"  -o Server.o CameraControlLib/Server.cpp
```

In this particular case, `DataServerLib.h` includes `CameraControlDefs.h` as shown below. The Ubuntu Linux `g++` compiler resolves the include file, `DataServerLib.h`, correctly using the `-I` preprocessor directive as shown below.
However, the `g++` compiler tells me that there is no such file or directory as `CameraControlDefs.h` even though I point a `-I` subdirectory path to `../../Utilities/DataServer`.

```
In file included from CameraControlLib/DataServer.h:4:0,
                 from CameraControlLib/DataServer.cpp:8:
CameraControlLib/DataServerLib.h:9:31: fatal error: CameraControlDefs.h: No such file or directory
 #include "CameraControlDefs.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
```

I know that if I use `#include "SomeDir/CameraControlDefs.h"`, that should get rid of the compiler error message. Please let me know if there is an alternate way to do this using the full range of Linux `g++` options.

Comment: Did you confirm that altering the source file as you suggest in your last paragraph in fact does get rid of the error? Testing that would ensure you understand the problem correctly.

Comment: Where does `CameraControlDefs.h` live exactly?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), in particular the chapter about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)? And also the documentation of [`cpp` preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)....? You really should read both of them (that won't be a time loss).

Comment: @David Schwartz, I just tried your suggestion by including the whole path to CameraControlDefs.h in DataServerLib.h and g++ tells me that there is no such file or directory,

Comment: @Etan Reisner, CameraControlDefs.h resides in $HOME/development/Hybrid/Utilitiies/DataServer.h.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch , Yes, I read the GCC documentation including invoke GCC as well as cpp preprocessor. However, I could not find anything to try to solve this problem.

Comment: Then, you should use `-H` to understand what is happenning at preprocessing phase; notice that `-I` wants *directories*

Comment: What do you mean `CameraControlDefs.h` resides in another file? Did you actually mean that? Also what is the current directory when you run g++?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch , Thank you for the -H preprocessor hint. I just tested David Schawrtz's idea of altering the source file to use the whole Linux include file path using the -H flag and Now the compiiler is not complaining anymore. May I ask if there is another way to do this with gcc or g++ without altering  the source file? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: I don't understand that question in the comment. You probably should either edit your posted question, or ask a new one, giving much more details. I would also suggest to dive into some small free software C++ project (and download & study its source code) to understand how it is dealing with very similar issues and take inspiration from that. And reading more seriously the documentation won't harm..

Comment: @Etan Reisner, #include "CameraControlDefs.h" resides in another C++ header file. That is what I meant by    CameraControlDefs.h resides in another file. The current directory is /home/testing/development/Hybrid/Recorder. Thank you.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, I apologize for the misunderstanding in my last comment . What I meant to ask is the only viable  option we have is to change  the line in  a C++ source file where the nested header file is specified to include either the full path or accurate relative path. I  willl study other source code  from an open source project as you recommend. Thank you.

Comment: Avoid absolute file paths in `#include` directives: `#include "/home/frank/includedir/foo.h"` is *always* a mistake

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, Thank you  for the information to  avoid absolute file paths.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,
  Here is a soution which I just tested in  a Makefile using g++ compiler

INCDIRS := $(addprefix -I,$(shell find  ../Utilities/DataServer  -type d -print))